# How can i import the world nodes to another .blend file?

Tags: node-editor, import, world

I would like to use the sky from [this](http://www.effeprod.net/spip.php?article69) file for another project. I tried to use copy/paste and Append, but none of them worked. Do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can append the world settings from this file to yours.

To append type <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or go to File --> Append.
Navigate to where you saved this file, then click it, and then the world "subfolder". Select the item called "World" within.

Then go to your world settings in the Properties Windows --> World Tab, and choose the new world (Probably "World.001") from the dropdown menu.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me on 2.79

Comment: after you append you have to go to the world dropdown to select the imported/appended world shader. See this for second step: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185873/how-to-append-a-world-with-hdri-and-nodes-from-another-blendfile

Answer (score 1):

As of **Blender 2.8+** you have to go to *File > Append*, select the `.blend` file and its *World* nodes.

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut has been removed in newer versions of Blender.