# How to Append a world with HDRi and nodes from another blendfile?

Tags: hdri, append, world

I can Append things from another blendfile if they're in Collections or various other groupings, but when I do Append -> blendfile -> World and select the World object, I get nothing appended. Is there any way to append a world? I specifically need the HDRi texture and the nodes around it.

Similarly I'd like to Append some nodes from a blendfile into the Compositor. Is that possible?

Comment: That should be the way. Are you sure there is the World shader you need in the file?

Comment: Pretty sure -- here's a pic of the source blendfile open in blender: https://pasteboard.co/JgVwHLJ.png

Comment: It probably got appended alright just not in use. If you want to use it you have to manually set it up afterwards

Comment: Hi @DuarteFarrajotaRamos; thanks, you're right -- @Nxdhin2005 's answer helped me figure out how to set it up.

Comment: Happy that you found it helpfull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To append an HDRi texture from another blend file along with the nodes :

1. append the world
2. select the world settings from the properties panel
3. Click on the *browse world settings to be linked*
4. In that you will see the appended world with the name ***World.001*** if it's not named and will appear with the name if it's named in the appended .blend file
   [image]

**The world will be appended along with the node setup**

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it. (Now I just have to figure out how to do that from Python, but I'm sure I can get that.)